# Variance does not completely match the one in Excel

Tags: c++, data-analysis, variance

I do not understand why is my variance not correct when there is a big input number. For `N > 10'000` the result of my variance does not match with the one in Excel. I modified the code so that I can input the numbers in the file and test them in Excel using `Var.p` function. The error is minimal (almost not relevant) but I don't know why do I get the error.
***Task***: Input is integer `N`  (could be very large). For `i=1`,`N`  you are to -compute random number `R` and then create two random variables `X=SqureRoot(1/r)` and `Y=Ln(1/r)`.
-You should compute `Var(X)` and `Var(Y)`.
***Restrictions***: Cannot use `ARRAY`s (or list, or anything…) In other words you cannot `MEMORISE X` or `Y`. Thus, you cannot use the standard formula for variance.

```cpp
int main()
{

        int N=0;
        cout << "N: "<< endl;
        cin>>N;
        srand(time(0));

        float sum1=0;
        float sum2=0;
        float sum3=0;
        float sum4=0;
        for (int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
                float X=sqrt(1.00/randZeroToOne());
                float Y=log(1.00/randZeroToOne());
                sum1=sum1+X;
                sum2=sum2+X*X;
                sum3=sum3+Y;
                sum4=sum4+Y*Y;
        }
        float n=N;

        float variance1=sum2/n - (sum1/n)*(sum1/n);
        float variance2=sum4/n - (sum3/n)*(sum3/n);
        cout<<"Varriance for X : "<<variance1<<endl;
        cout<<"Varriance for Y : "<<variance2<<endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may try using `double` instead of `float`. Rounding errors may become important when summing many elements.

Comment: Given that your code is calculating the variances of two randomly generated sequences, some variability is to be expected, unless you have somehow managed to ensure that the exact-same sequences are generated in both Exel and C++.    That means you need to be generating exactly the same sets of (pseudo) random values, and that Excel and your C++ implementation do calculations to identical precision.   Even changing `float` to `double` is not *guaranteed* to produce the same result, every time.